# Bond percolation probability on a Bethe lattice

Tags: probability, solution-verification, random-graphs, network, percolation

I derived the bond-percolation probability for a Bethe lattice and my result disagrees with a seemingly reputable reference by Albert & Barabasi (see below).

I would be happy if somebody could find my mistake, or, verify my result with an alternate reference (I tried to find one without success).

**Problem** Consider the Bethe graph (see below), where each node is connected to $3$ neighbors. From this lattice we construct a random graph, where each link exists with a given, fixed probability $p\in[0,1]$.

[image: Bethe lattice]

Our goal is to compute the percolation probability $P(p)$, that a given, fixed node is connected to infinity. By symmetry we can identify this arbitrary node with the origin.

**(1)** First we consider the white nodes (see the picture) and restrict to paths which only move away from the origin (i.e. from smaller to larger circles). Let $w$ be the probability, that one *cannot* reach infinity from such a white note. Then $w$ fulfills

$$w=(1-p+pw)^2.$$

This is because the path does either stop at the next link ($=1-p$) or it follows the link, but the next node does not lead to infinity ($=pw$). As there are two possible next links, $(1-p+pw)$ is squared. Solving this equation gives

$$w=\left(\frac{1}{p}-1\right)^2.$$

**(2)** Let $W$ be the probability, that one cannot reach infinity from the origin into any direction. Using the same idea as above, but keeping in mind that now there are *three* directions, we have

$$W=(1-p+pw)^3=w^{3/2}=\left(\frac{1}{p}-1\right)^3.$$

**(3)** Thus, the probability for reaching infinity is

$$P(p)=1-W=\frac{p^3-(1-p)^3}{p^3}.$$

I could not find any mistake, however, in [this review article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0106096v1) Albert & Barabasi claim that

$$P(p)=\frac{2p-1}{p^2},$$

(see Eq.(31)), referring again to *Stauffer,Aharony, Introduction to percolation theory, London, 1992*. However, in the book by Stauffer & Aharony I could not find this problem, but only a treatment of the *site*-percolation problem (where not the links, but the *sites* are occupied randomly) with a different result, while Albert & Barabasi explicitly consider *bond*-percolation (see 2nd paragraph of Sec. IV.C).

Now I wonder who is wrong, me or Albert & Barabasi ;)

Comment: @Did This would explain it, but I doubt they do. Can you tell me where this is stated? I find no remark on this and Fig.12 shows the tree with root degree 3.

Comment: OK, I consulted more carefully the sources you indicate. Summary: First, A&B's reference to S&A is phony (note that it is rather folklore in the milieu that A&B's papers link rather more than is usual to irrelevant sources, probably because of their hastiness to write their papers). Second, your approach is sound up to the point when you use $w^{3/2}=(p-1)^3/p^3$ instead of $w^{3/2}=(1-p)^3/p^3$ (note the signs). If you correct this step, your end result should be allright. (Sorry for the first, irrelevant, comment.)

Comment: @Did thanks I corrected that. When you said that my end result should now be "alright", did you also expect it to resolve the disagreement to B&A? Because it still differs (see edit).